# In Django select related field via foreign key

Tags: python, django

I am aware of that to select a related object one should do `object.related_set.all()`. Yet in my situation this produces an AttributeError, so it's very hard to debug. Here is the setup:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    ...

class FieldDiff(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action, editable=False, related_name='Action')
```

And in a shell:

```
In [16]: act = Action.objects.get(pk=34)
In [17]: act.fielddiff_set.all()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/ipantuyev/progs/ccc_app/<ipython console> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'Action' object has no attribute 'fielddiff_set'
```

I suppose this has to do with translation from camelcase. I can go around this, but this code would be called from the template, so I would rather have no extra logic.

Comment: Thanks guys. Should've caught that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you specified `related_name` to be `Action`. This means you want to access all `FieldDiff` instances associated with an `Action` via `Action_set`. Since it seems like this isn't what you want, the simplest solution is to remove the `related_name` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "translation from camelcase".

You have given your ForeignKey an explicit `related_name` attribute. This is the name that Django uses to provide the reverse relationship. So your query should be:

```
act.Action.all()
```

Actually, that related_name value makes no sense. You should remove it, then the original `fielddiff_set` would work.